# raiserror shows one message, but not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this code:

```
DECLARE
   @timestamp varchar(20),
   @latestFeed INT,
   @LargestKeyProcessed INT,
   @NextBatchMax INT,
   @RC INT;

   SET @timestamp = CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as varchar(20));
   SET @latestFeed = (SELECT MAX([feed_id]) FROM [dbo].[CAQH_RESP_ALL_TEST_MIRROR]);
   SET @LargestKeyProcessed = (SELECT MIN([record_id]) - 1 FROM [dbo].[CAQH_RESP_ALL_TEST_MIRROR] WHERE [feed_id] = @latestFeed);
   SET @NextBatchMax = 1;
   SET @RC = (SELECT MAX([record_id]) FROM [dbo].[CAQH_RESP_ALL_TEST_MIRROR]);

raiserror(@timestamp, 0, 1) with nowait
raiserror(@LargestKeyProcessed, 0, 2) with nowait

WHILE (@NextBatchMax < @RC)
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        --do some stuff

        COMMIT TRANSACTION flagHandling
        raiserror('Transaction Committed', 0, 3) with nowait
        raiserror(@timestamp, 0, 4) with nowait
        raiserror(@LargestKeyProcessed, 0, 5) with nowait
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --catch some stuff
    END CATCH
END
```

It seems to run fine, but has a couple of things that seem odd to me.  At the outset, it prints the date as I'd expect to see it, but then prints an actual error message with the raiserror I'm using.  I'm using the exact same syntax, but one prints only the desired timestamp, while the next produces

```
Jul 23 2015  9:09AM
Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Error 33218606, severity 0, state 2 was raised, but no message with that    
error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, 
make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.
```

Then, after the transaction is committed, it correctly shows the following messages:

```
Transaction Committed
Jul 23 2015  9:11AM
```

But leaves out the last message which should show the value of `@LargestKeyProcessed`.  This raiserror message is the same one as the raiserror message at the beginning of the script that produces the aforementioned odd behavior.

I just want to have the messages print to the messages window without looking like an error, and also want to have ALL the messages print.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're giving an int to raiserror, which means you're using the msg_id functionality:

```
RAISERROR ( { msg_id | msg_str | @local_variable }
    { ,severity ,state }
    [ ,argument [ ,...n ] ] )
    [ WITH option [ ,...n ] ]
```

msg_id:

> Is a user-defined error message number stored in the sys.messages
>   catalog view using sp_addmessage. Error numbers for user-defined error
>   messages should be greater than 50000. When msg_id is not specified,
>   RAISERROR raises an error message with an error number of 50000.

You should use varchar variables, and that can then contain the number which you want to send. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx).

Comment: that totally makes sense.  I didn't look at the documentation closely enough. Solved both issues!